# How insert/delete/update table automatically by another table in SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, visual-studio

I created a windows form app using visual studio 2017 and MS SQL Server 2016. 
It's working correctly. SQL table contains

```
tblMain(HomeID,Bed,Location,Address,Town,Province)
```

When I *insert/update/delete* it's working.

I also created 2 tables

`tblHome` (HomeID,Bed,Location) and `tblLocation` (Address,Town,Province).

Now I need to *insert/update/delete* `tblMain` through my windows form app and automatically *insert/update/delete* `tblHome` and `tblLocation` tables`.

Is this possible?

Comment: Yes, updating tables is possible.  Your question is too broad.

Comment: use trigger in table tblHome for Insert/Update/Delete.

Comment: Looks like you probably do some research on database normalization. `tblMain` maybe shouldn't repeat the columns from `tblLocation` and `tblHome` but just reference them. If there are good reasons why this cannot be done `tblMain` should probably rather be a view selecting from the other tables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A trigger is a special type of stored procedure that automatically runs when an event occurs in the database server. DML triggers run when a user tries to modify data through a data manipulation language (DML) event. DML events are INSERT, UPDATE, or DELETE statements on a table or view.

https://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Simple-Insert-Update-and-Delete-Triggers-in-SQL-Server-with-example.aspx